# CakePHP External Link

Tags: cakephp, hyperlink, external

I have a website that has links which, if clicked, should open a new tab and load that particular website.

I've tried using this example:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link('CakeBook', 'http://cakephp.org', array('class'=> 'myclass', 'target'=>'_blank')); ?>
```

The problem is it isn't even clickable. I'm using CakePHP 2.5.5

Comment: working fine here...maybe you got a problem with css that is overlapping your link? 
did you try it on an empty page?

Comment: I have tried this code and it is working good.